# Piping string with folders in variable to findstr - copy and rename files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, pipe, findstr

I'm trying to pipe a string that contains folder paths to `findstr` to search for a particular part in the names of the given folders - or at least, that is what I'm planning to do.

I've got a source folder with files that have to be copied into multiple subfolders and after that, one of the copied files has to be renamed corresponding to the destination folder. If there already are files with the same names, they have to be overwritten. I am trying to achieve this via `.bat`-file using the following commands in my code:

```
pushd ..\..\destination_folder\

FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /AD /S /B^| findstr /I "._Modul_X$"') do copy ..\xxx\yyy\ressources\*.* %%i
& ren %%i\xxxx_Modul_X.BAT_TEMPLATE" "%%i_Modul_X.BAT_TEMPLATE
```

The `copy`-part seems to work, the `rename`-part does not and when it comes to overwriting the one file that has to be renamed after copying it (name conflict!), I'm pretty clueless how to do this (`IF EXIST` & `DEL`?).

Comment: Is there really a line-break after the `copy` command, so the next line begins with `&`? I guess there should not be one. And the search string should read `\._Modul_X$` (note the backslash to escape the `.`, which otherwise meant *any character*). Finally your quotation needs to be fixed; best is to quote *all* paths...

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! There is no line break, I used a smartphone to type in my question and... yeah, well... you know the rest ;-) Unfortunately, I've got like zero experience in doing stuff like this, so it is a little hard for me to figure out what is wrong in my code...

Comment: This is the only way the copy part is working, for the rename part, I'm getting a syntax error: FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /AD /S /B^| findstr "._Modul_X"') do copy "..\xxx\yyy\ressources\*.*" "%%i" & ren "%%i\xxxx_Modul_X.BAT_TEMPLATE" "%%Modul_X.BAT_TEMPLATE" . No matches are found if I'm changing the search string as suggested.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's just terrible! Please [edit] your question instead and add the code there -- properly formatted, then one can read it...

Comment: Yep, you've got a point there! I'm sorry and edited my question as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: `ren` takes a pure filename only as the second parameter (no path).

Comment: @PhilGee, I've rolled back your previous edit(s). You do not add answers directly to your question. There is nothing wrong with you answering your own question, so please add the solution as an answer, if it is indeed a solution, and not simply updated code, together with another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the process you're attempting, then the following should do as you require, *subject to my assumption that `xxxx` is a sequence of exactly four, digits (directory names), and characters (file names)*:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

PushD "..\..\destination_folder" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF
If Not Exist "..\xxx\yyy\resources\*.*" GoTo :EOF

For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    'Dir /B /S /A:D "????_Modul_X" 2^>NUL ^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe^
     /I /R "\\[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]_Modul_X"'
) Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%H In (
        '%__AppDir__%where.exe /F "%%G":"????_Modul_X.BAT_TEMPLATE" 2^>NUL'
    ) Do Del /A /F %%H
    Copy /Y "..\xxx\yyy\resources\*.*" "%%G" 1>NUL
    For /F "Delims=" %%I In (
        '%__AppDir__%where.exe /F "%%G":"????_Modul_X.BAT_TEMPLATE" 2^>NUL'
    ) Do If /I Not "%%~nxI" == "%%~nxG%%~xI" Ren %%I "%%~nxG%%~xI"
)
```

Please note that you will probably need to modify both instances of `xxx\yyy\resources`, *(lines `5` and `14`)*, as nobody really uses names like that, *paying special attention to the spelling, I've used `resources` above, not `ressources`*.